# How to apply focus visual style for a button without actually focusing it?

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to get a similar effect as the Windows Run dialog. The input box is focused and taking input, and the "OK" button also gets the focused border(but not actually focused). I can't find a way to set button's visual style properly...

C# Winform, .net 4.5(higher version is also OK).

[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `AcceptButton` on the form it self.
Select the `okButton` on the form `AcceptButton` property to make it the default action on `Enter` keypress.

You also have a similar action for the `CancelButton` that triggers on `Escape` keypress.